# Apply callback to 2 arbitrary length arrays using functional programming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Given that these function declarations exist within scope:

```
function compose() {
  var funcs = arguments;

  return function() {
    var args, i;

    args = arguments;

    for (i = funcs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      args = [funcs[i].apply(null, args)];
    }

    return args[0];
  };
}

function id(x) {
  return x;
}

function partial(targetfn) {
  var arity = targetfn.length;

  return function fn() {
    if (arguments.length < arity) {
      return Function.prototype.bind.apply(fn, [null].concat(
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
      ));
    } else {
      return targetfn.apply(null, arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

Having this callback function as an example:

```
function cb(x, y) {
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
```

Is it possible using FP techniques (such as argument binding, composition and partial application) to apply the callback function to 2 arrays of arbitrary length? E.g.: `["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"]` and `[12, 42]`? The expected output in this case would be:

```
foo
12
foo
42
bar
12
bar
42
baz
12
...and so on
```

Since `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.map` pass 3 arguments to the callback function, it's at least possible to iterate over a single array using function composition as follows:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"].forEach(compose(cb, id))
```

It's also possible to map an array into partially applied functions like so:

```
[12, 42].map(compose(partial(cb), id))
```

I've been looking into using `Function.prototype.apply`, `Function.prototype.bind` and `Function.prototype.call`, combining them with `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.map`, so far without success. I'm trying hard not to introduce more function declarations / expressions.

### Update

Thanks to Mulan, the problem can be solved by splitting it into the part that computes the cartesian product of lists and applying the resulting list to a given function.

```
function product() {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

  return args.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    var ret = [];

    prev.forEach(function(x) {
      cur.forEach(function(y) {
        ret.push(x.concat(y));
      });
    });

    return ret;
  }, args.shift().map(function(val) {
    return [val];
  }));
}

product(
  ["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"],
  [12, 42]
).forEach(Function.prototype.apply.bind(cb, null));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be making more work for yourself by forcing `compose` and `partial` where they're not particularly useful. It seems like you're looking to compute a `product` of input arrays. The result is an array of products, each of which contains a unique grouping of elements taken from the input arrays -

```js
function product(a, ...more) {
  if (more.length == 0)
    return a.map(v => [v])
  else 
    return a.flatMap(v => product(...more).map(p => [v, ...p]))
}

function cb(x,y) {
  console.log(x, y)
}

product(["foo", "bar", "baz", "quux"], [12, 42])
  .forEach(p => cb(...p))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

If you really want to use `partial`, you can accept a callback `cb` as the first argument, and then all arrays to multiply thereafter. Each step in `product` applies one argument to `cb`. The result is an array of products where each product is an array of partially applied functions, which can be executed by calling `cb()` -

```js
function partial(f, ...x) {
  return (...y) => f(...x, ...y)
}

function product(cb, a, ...more) {
  if (more.length == 0)
    return a.map(v => partial(cb, v))
  else
    return a.flatMap(v => product(partial(cb, v), ...more))
}

const cb = partial(console.log, "i would like")

const res = product(cb,
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", ""],
  ["", "☕️"]
 )

res.forEach(cb => cb())
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```